# If a function is continuous at 0, find the values of two constants a and b

Tags: calculus

[image]

What approach should I take? I am practising for my Calc Final and I've some problems trying to understand these kind of examples.

Comment: 1st thing to do is to make sure you know what "continuous" means. Do you?

Comment: I know that as x gets closer to a, f x gets closer to f a, but I can't find a way to using that in my advantage

Comment: Can you figure out what $(\log(2+x)-\log2)/x$ gets closer to as $x$ gets closer to zero?

Comment: the greater x gets the closer f x gets to 0 if that's what you mean

Comment: No, I mean what I wrote; "as $x$ gets closer to zero".

Comment: the answer is e, but I had to use a calculator to find the values of f(x) and then conclude they indeed approach to 0.5 from both sides... 

If I want to do this without a calc, do I need to learn the values of ln?

Comment: Presumably, you have learned some methods for evaluating limits. Maybe you have learned l'Hopital's Rule. Or maybe you can recognize $$\lim_{x\to0}{\log(2+x)-\log2\over x}$$ from the definition of the derivative, as applied to the logarithm function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should basically know that if a function $f$ is continuous at $x=a$ then,

$$f(a)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$$